# Anchor tag not working - not sure why

Tags: html

My anchor tags aren't functioning properly. When I click one, it focuses down then back up. Any ideas as to why? And how I can fix it to anchor properly?

URL: http://www.amleo.com/spreaders/a/88/

The anchor I'm mainly testing is the Snow & Winter one, because it's at the bottom.

Code:

```
<body>
<table width="720" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><h2><b>Having a spreader, that fits the needs of your business, is invaluable. With hundreds of options in the market place, its important to know what type of spreader is best for you.</b></h2>
      <br>
      <h3>Hopper:</h3> </b><strong>Choose based on the material you will be applying. Steel hoppers are built to stand up to hard use, while poly are more ecconomical. <b></strong><br>
        <br>
      <b><h3>Capacity:</h3>
      </b>This is the weight capacity of the hopper and frame, not the volume. For example, you may not be able to fit in 100 lbs. of a lightweight product, such as grass seed, in a 100lb spreader.<br>
      <br><b><h3>
      Frame:</h3>
      </b>Choose powder coated frames to stand up to hard materials. Stainless steel frames are more resistant to rust. <br><b><h3>
      Type:</h3>
      </b>
      Broadcast spreaders are not as precise as drop spreaders, but are more forgiving due to overlap. Drop spreaders special attention needs to be taken to ensure you do not cause striping, especially when applying fertilizer materials. <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Types Of Spreaders: (Click on each type to see details)<br>
        <a href="/spreader/a/88/#hand">Hand Carry</a><br>
        <a href="#walk">Walk-Behind</a><br>
        <a href="#tow">Tow-Behind/Mounted</a><br>
        <a href="/spreaders/a/88/#snow">Snow and Winter</a><br>
        <br></h3>
</table>
     <h3><a name="hand">Hand-Carry Spreaders-</a></h3>

    <table width="720" border=".5">Hand-carry spreaders offer adjustable settings based on the type of material you are using. Each model and brand may vary, but for the most part you will have different settings for applying seed, fertilizer or other materials.  Ideal for smaller areas.

        <tr>
        <td width="88">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="142"><strong>Hopper</strong></td>
        <td width="135"><strong> Capacity</strong></td>
        <td width="170"><strong>Frame</strong></td>
        <td width="65"><strong>Port</a></strong></td>
        <td width="94"><strong>Price</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="88"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=3100E">3100E</a></strong></td>
        <td width="142">Poly</td>
        <td width="135">40lbs</td>
        <td width="170">Powder Coated</td>
        <td>Multi</a></td>
        <td width="94">$135.39</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="88"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=e27">E27</a></strong></td>
        <td width="142">Nylon Bag</td>
        <td width="135">20lbs</td>
        <td width="170">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Single</a></td>
        <td width="94">$45.29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="88"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=421S">421S</a></strong></td>
        <td width="142">Poly</td>
        <td width="135">20lbs</td>
        <td width="170">&nbsp;</td>
        <td></a></td>
        <td width="94">$86.99</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="88"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=t711">T771</a></strong></td>
        <td width="142">Poly</td>
        <td width="135">20lbs</td>
        <td width="170">Stainless Steel</td>
        <td></a></td>
        <td width="94">$125.99</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="88" height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=3200e">3200E</a></strong></td>
        <td width="142">Poly</td>
        <td width="135">25lbs</td>
        <td width="170">Poly</td>
        <td>Multi</td>
        <td width="94">$99.99</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="88" height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=E34">E34</a></strong></td>
        <td width="142">Poly</td>
        <td width="135">1.8 liter</td>
        <td width="170">Poly</td>
        <td></td>
        <td width="94">$17.79</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
      <br>
      <b><h3><a name="walk">Walk-Behind Spreaders-
        </a></h3>
      </b> Optional deflectors help you get close enough to sidewalks, flower beds, or drives without actually spreading material in unwanted spaces.
<table width="720" border=".5">
        <tr>
          <td width="102">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="79"><strong>Type</strong></td>
          <td width="87"><strong>Hopper</strong></td>
          <td width="83"><strong> Capacity</strong></td>
          <td width="157"><strong>Frame</strong></td>
          <td width="91"><strong>Port</a></strong></td>
          <td width="91"><strong>Price</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="102"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=vp-am100">AM100P</a></strong></td>
          <td width="79">Broadcast</td>
          <td width="87">Poly</td>
          <td width="83">100lbs</td>
          <td width="157">Powder Coated </td>
          <td>Multi</td>
          <td width="91">$399.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=vp-am100">AM100S</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>100lbs</td>
          <td>Stainless Steel</td>
          <td>Multi</td>
          <td>$469.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="102"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=vp-am70">AM70S</a></strong></td>
          <td width="79">Broadcast</td>
          <td width="87">Poly</td>
          <td width="83">70lbs</td>
          <td width="157">Stainless Steel</td>
          <td>Single</td>
          <td width="91">$369.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=vp-am70">AM70S</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>70lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>Single</td>
          <td>$299.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=3200e">AM50P</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>50lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>Single</td>
          <td>$124.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=22app">22APP</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>50lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>Multi</td>
          <td>$269.89</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=vp-p60">P6090</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Stainless Steel</td>
          <td>110lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>$449.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=vp-p60">S6090</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Stainless Steel</td>
          <td>110lbs</td>
          <td>Stainless Steel</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>$549.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=36h12">36H12</a></strong></td>
          <td>Drop</td>
          <td>Steel</td>
          <td>120lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>Multi</td>
          <td>$457.79</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=36h13">36H13</a></strong></td>
          <td>Drop</td>
          <td>Steel</td>
          <td>120lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>Multi</td>
          <td>$529.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=2130">2130</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>65lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>Single</td>
          <td>$275.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=2130ss">2130SS</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>65lbs</td>
          <td>Stainless Steel</td>
          <td>Single</td>
          <td>$399.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=24p">24P</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>100lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>Multi</td>
          <td>$398.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=C24HDS-NC">C24HDS-NC</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>100lbs</td>
          <td>Stainless Steel</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>$547.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=S60120">S60120</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>120lbs</td>
          <td>Stainless Steel</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>$589.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=vp-psk">P4050</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly </td>
          <td>50lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>$294.79</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=vp-psk">S4050</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>50lbs</td>
          <td>Stainless Steel</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>$396.89</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=2170PRO">2170PRO</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>100lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>Multi</td>
          <td>$234.49</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=2040pip">2040PIP</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>65lb</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>Single</td>
          <td>$132.69</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="21"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=p2090">P2090</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Steel</td>
          <td>40lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>$214.79</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="21"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=p6080">P6080</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>80lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>$352.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="21"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=s6080">S6080</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>80lbs</td>
          <td>Stainless Steel</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>$479.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="21"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=sp46">SP46</a></strong></td>
          <td>Broadcast</td>
          <td>Poly</td>
          <td>55lbs</td>
          <td>Powder Coated</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>$139.99</td>
        </tr>
    </table>      
<br />
<br><b>
<h3>
<a name="tow">Tow-Behind/Mounted Spreaders-</a>
</h3></b>These spreaders are ideal for larger areas. 

<table width="720" border=".5">
  <tr>
    <td width="88">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="142"><strong>Type</strong></td>
    <td width="142"><strong>Style</strong></td>
    <td width="142"><strong>Hopper</strong></td>
    <td width="135"><strong> Capacity</strong></td>
    <td width="170"><strong>Frame</strong></td>
    <td width="65"><strong>Port</a></strong></td>
    <td width="94"><strong>Price</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=vp-am100">AM100T</a></strong></td>
    <td width="142">Broadcast</td>
    <td width="142">Tow-Behind</td>
    <td width="142">Poly</td>
    <td width="135">100lbs</td>
    <td width="170">Stainless Steel</td>
    <td>Multi</a></td>
    <td width="94">$469.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=c25hds">C25HDS</a></strong></td>
    <td width="142">Broadcast</td>
    <td width="142">Tow-Behind</td>
    <td width="142">Poly</td>
    <td width="135">100lbs</td>
    <td width="170">Stainless Steel</td>
    <td>Multi</td>
    <td width="94">$572.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=S30175">S30175</a></strong></td>
    <td width="142">Broadcast</td>
    <td width="142">Tow-Behind</td>
    <td width="142">Poly</td>
    <td width="135">175lbs</td>
    <td width="170">Stainless Steel</td>
    <td></a></td>
    <td width="94">$486.19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=M40">M40</a></strong></td>
    <td width="142">Broadcast</td>
    <td width="142">Mounted</td>
    <td width="142">Poly</td>
    <td width="135">100lbs</td>
    <td width="170">Stainless Steel</td>
    <td></a>Multi</td>
    <td width="94">$936.39</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88" height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=P30175">P30175</a></strong></td>
    <td width="142">Broadcast</td>
    <td width="142">Tow-Behind</td>
    <td width="142">Poly</td>
    <td width="135">175lbs</td>
    <td width="170">Powder Coated</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="94">$317.29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88" height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=6506T18">6506T18</a></strong></td>
    <td width="142">Drop</td>
    <td width="142">Tow-Behind</td>
    <td width="142">Steel</td>
    <td width="135">6 cu ft</td>
    <td width="170">Powder Coated</td>
    <td>Multi</td>
    <td width="94">$1599.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=6505t18">6505T18</a></strong></td>
    <td>Drop</td>
    <td>Tow-Behind</td>
    <td>Steel</td>
    <td>5 cu ft</td>
    <td>Powder Coated</td>
    <td>Multi</td>
    <td>$1519.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=36t13">36T13</a></strong></td>
    <td>Drop</td>
    <td>Tow-Behind</td>
    <td>Steel</td>
    <td>120lbs</td>
    <td>Powder Coated</td>
    <td>Multi</td>
    <td>$551.49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=M80ecm">M80ECM</a></strong></td>
    <td>Broadcast</td>
    <td>Mounted</td>
    <td>Poly</td>
    <td>250lbs</td>
    <td>Stainless Steel</td>
    <td>Multi</td>
    <td>$1113.49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=M20">M20</a></strong></td>
    <td>Broadcast</td>
    <td>Mounted</td>
    <td>Poly</td>
    <td>80lbs</td>
    <td>Powder Coated</td>
    <td>Multi</td>
    <td>$223.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=M30">M30</a></strong></td>
    <td>Broadcast</td>
    <td>Mounted</td>
    <td>Poly</td>
    <td>100lbs</td>
    <td>Powder Coated</td>
    <td>Multi</td>
    <td>$348.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=M21p">M21P</a></strong></td>
    <td>Broadcast</td>
    <td>Mounted</td>
    <td>Poly</td>
    <td>100lbs</td>
    <td>Powder Coated</td>
    <td>Multi</td>
    <td>$399.89</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=c25hd">C25HD</a></strong></td>
    <td>Broadcast</td>
    <td>Tow-Behind</td>
    <td>Poly</td>
    <td>100lb</td>
    <td>Powder Coated</td>
    <td>Multi</td>
    <td>$477.49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=s30125">S30125</a></strong></td>
    <td>Broadcast</td>
    <td>Tow-Behind</td>
    <td>Poly</td>
    <td>125lb</td>
    <td>Stainless Steel</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>$453.19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=2170t">2170T</a></strong></td>
    <td>Broadcast</td>
    <td>Tow-Behind</td>
    <td>Poly</td>
    <td>100lbs</td>
    <td>Powder Coated</td>
    <td>Multi</td>
    <td>$243.79</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=6504t18">6504T18</a></strong></td>
    <td>Drop</td>
    <td>Tow-Behind</td>
    <td>Steel</td>
    <td>4 cu ft</td>
    <td>Powder Coated</td>
    <td>Multi</td>
    <td>$1477.59</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/><br><b><h3><a name="snow">Snow and Winter Spreaders- </a></h3>
</b>Low maintenance style and versatility make these spreaders last season after season. Designed to spread a variety of ice melt and rock salt products. 
<table width="720" border=".5">
  <tr>
    <td width="88">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="142"><strong>Style</strong></td>
    <td width="142"><strong>Hopper</strong></td>
    <td width="135"><strong> Capacity</strong></td>
    <td width="170"><strong>Frame</strong></td>
    <td width="65"><strong>Port</a></strong></td>
    <td width="94"><strong>Price</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=sd95">SD95</a></strong></td>
    <td width="142">Walk-Behind</td>
    <td width="142">Poly</td>
    <td width="135">160lbs</td>
    <td width="170">Powder Coated</td>
    <td>Single</td>
    <td width="94">$599.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=sd95ss">SD95SS</a></strong></td>
    <td width="142">Walk-Behind</td>
    <td width="142">Poly</td>
    <td width="135">160lbs</td>
    <td width="170">Stainless Steel</td>
    <td>Single</a></td>
    <td width="94">$721.39</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=sr210x">SR210X</a></strong></td>
    <td width="142">Mounted</td>
    <td width="142">Poly</td>
    <td width="135">240lbs / 3 cu ft</td>
    <td width="170">Powder Coated</td>
    <td></a>Single</td>
    <td width="94">$599.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88"><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=sp225x">SP225X</a></strong></td>
    <td width="142">Mounted</td>
    <td width="142">Poly</td>
    <td width="135">240lbs / 3 cu ft</td>
    <td width="170">Powder Coated</td>
    <td></a></td>
    <td width="94">$749.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88" height=""><strong><a href="http://www.amleo.com/product.aspx?p=sp125x">SP125X</a></strong></td>
    <td width="142">Mounted</td>
    <td width="142">Poly</td>
    <td width="135">240lbs / 3 cu ft</td>
    <td width="170">Poweder Coated</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="94">$810.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><b>
</b></br>
<b>
<h3>&nbsp; </h3>
</b></td>
  </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine using the url you provided. Clicking the 'Snow and Winter' link goes down to the 'Snow and Winter' anchor. Are you testing in different envioronment? What browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with the anchor. You have some javascript event that is causing the scroll to return to the top. You can see this if you reload the page and quickly scroll down after a half a second or so it jumps back to the top once. The same thing is happening after you click the anchor tag.

I'm not sure what script is causing it yet, but that is where I'd look.

*Update*: In dmcommon.js you have the following code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 1)
    }, 10)
}
```